# Matlab: How to create a custom fit type function (for use with fit) for an arbitrary number of independent variables?

Tags: matlab

I know how to create a [custom fit type](http://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/fittype.html) for a case, say, where there are two independent variables and one dependent variable:

`ft = fittype(@(a, b, x1, x2, y) a*x1 + b*x2, 'coefficients', {'a', 'b'}, 'independent', {'x1', 'x2'}, 'dependent', {'y'})`

However, what if I can't assume the number of independent variables? For instance, I might have 10, instead of 2. How can I create a custom fit type for a variable number of independent variables?

Comment: It might be easier to avoid `fittype` and just write your own fitting algorithm, depending on your application.

Comment: @David You mean avoid `fit`?

Comment: Both! (Maybe not, but in general writing code to do fitting is fairly simple and will let you do just what you want, in particular, using vectors for coefficients, which I don't think `fit`/`fittype` can do)

Comment: @David Thanks. I'll give that some thought!

Comment: Feel free to modify this question or ask a new one if you have trouble with your own fitting function, but it's still more than possible that someone will be able to make `fittype` work for you.

Comment: Couldn't you put the multiple variables into one variable, as a matrix? If not, `varargin` might help.